# Websphere application server additing/deleting MIME type in WAS 6.1

Tags: websphere, mime

I am using WAS 6.1 and I have tried to add the MIME type ".msg" (outlook email format) through the admin console and deleted the ".docx" mime type

But even after all these, ".msg" files when I try open from my application using IE, its not detecting and showing as scrambled characters and the ".docx" files it still recognizes even though I have deleted them

What is the best way to check what are the supported (so that I can check .msg exists) and unsupported mime types (to check .docx is removed)

Please let me know
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be done/checked from admin console of IBM